# Inserting a mysql row with DateTime using Doctrine DQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, doctrine, dql

I am having some trouble trying to insert a row in my MySQL table using Doctrine DQL, specifically, the row inserts correctly but the "created" column shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00 on my table.

Here is my entity:

```
    class Packages
    {
        [... more irrelevant fields ...]
        /**
        * @var \DateTime
        * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
        */
        private $created;
    }
```

Here is my code to insert:

```
    $packages = new Packages;
    $packages->setCreated(new \DateTime("now"));
    [... more setters here ...]
    print_r($packages);  // See below for the print_r output
    $em = self::getEntityManager();        
    try{
        $em->persist($packages);
        $em->flush();
        return $packages->getPackageId();
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
```

print_r output here, and then the ID was returned correctly:

```
    Core\Entities\Packages Object
    (
        [..... More irrelevant fields set correctly .....]
        [created:Core\Entities\Packages:private] => DateTime Object        
        (
            [date] => 2013-12-02 09:37:18
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
        )
    )
```

But then this happened

```
    mysql> select created from packages where package_id=1694;
    +---------------------+
    | created             |
    +---------------------+
    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
    +---------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone have any clue about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try
1) set created in constructor
OR
2) use [Lifecycle Callbacks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html) prePersist